Multiple Port authentication support for NextJS and JSP Spring Boot
We are currently working on a web application using NextJS, which represents the latest version of our system. Our previous system relies on JSP and Spring Boot. Our strategy is to gradually shift from the old system to the new one. In the interim, we need to implement authentication support so that users who log into the new NextJS application can also access the JSP user interface of the old system. For navigation purposes, we will redirect users to the old system until the new user interface is fully developed in NextJS.
It's important to note that both the NextJS app and the Spring Boot JSP will be hosted on the same domain but will operate on different ports. What would be the most effective approach to achieve this?
